# Master Data Explorer disables Model and Entities after every action in Excel

Tags: excel, sql-server-2014, master-data-services

I'm working with SQL Server 2014 and Excel 2013 with the Master Data Services Add-on (SQL Server and Excel are both trial versions.)

When I connect to the model then I perform any action on an entity in that model, the Model and the list of Entities in the Master Data Explorer panel become disabled and I have to close the pane, reconnect to the MDS server and select the model again.

My MDS security settings are fine because I can edit the entities I want from Excel, it's just the disabling that is a pain.

Is this the behaviour of the trial version? I haven't found anything that says it is.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Master Data Explorer panel works primarily for a new empty worksheet. If you are viewing a worksheet already populated with an entity and its attributes, there's nothing for the Panel to do. Use the tool bar buttons on the Master Data tab to manipulate an entity. Use the panel to open existing entities into a blank worksheet.